# Don't split revision string in the footer

Tags: bug, status-completed, localization, footer, revision-number

For better localization there is need to add an explicit non-breakable space or allow to translare string like `rev 2017.10.20.27536` in the footer via Transifex.

E.g. now in [SO in Russian](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/) and [SO in Japanese](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/) it looks splitted:

> [image: ja]

> [image: ru]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting with the next build, there will be an `&nbsp;` between "rev" and the actual revision number.